# Quick way to merging similar items in a list in java

Tags: java, list, merge

For example I have this list:

```
myList = ['2','3','a','b','c','3','5','£','a','4',5','=']
```

I want to merge similar elements together if they are next to each other.
So I want to end up with a new list, like this:

```
newList = ['23', 'abc', '35', '£', 'a', '45', '=']
```

Comment: How do you define a 'similar' element?

Comment: Quick note: ' is only valid for characters in Java, not for strings. As for the problem, there is the simplest solution to just check the character value and see if it's in the same "class" (that you define) as the previous one.

Comment: How can you make `2`, `3` into `23` and call them similarly grouped?

Comment: Are the elements in the list supposed to stay the same type, primitive or otherwise? Your example needs clarification on that point as well: '2' is a valid char, '23' is not.

Comment: Please specify the type of newList

Comment: @SumitJain it should hold them as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a method to test similarity and use this to combine characters into a String.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Character> myList = Arrays.asList('2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c', '3', '5', '£', 'a', '4', '5', '=');
    List<String> grouped = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder group = new StringBuilder();
    String prevType = null;
    for (Character ch : myList) {
        String type = typeOf(ch);
        if (prevType != null && type != prevType) {
            grouped.add(group.toString());
            group.setLength(0);
        }
        group.append(ch);
        prevType = type;
    }
    grouped.add(group.toString());
    System.out.println("myList= " + myList);
    System.out.println("newList= " + grouped);
}

private static String typeOf(Character ch) {
    return Character.isDigit(ch) ? "digit" :
            Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? "alpha" :
                    "other";
}
```

prints

```
myList= [2, 3, a, b, c, 3, 5, £, a, 4, 5, =]
newList= [23, abc, 35, £, a, 45, =]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd read every char in the list and cast it to int, to get it's ascii code.

Nextly you can define code range for similar characters - here you can make private methods like `isDigit(char c)` `isUpperLetter(char c)` `isSpecialCharacter(char c)` `isArabic(char c)` and so on.

Lastly - during reading the list char by char you need to have a flag informing you about the type of last character - if this one isn't the same - you start concating new string for you `newList`

EDIT: @refp just wrote what I was talking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would just iterate through the items in a loop, and create a new list that you add your merged items into.  This doesn't seem a great question tbh.